Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake while trying to connect with kafka server by a consumer
I'm trying to setup SASL plain authentication in kafka. But when I try to read a message or send a message, the Kafka Server logs the following error:
INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (channelId=127.0.0.1:9092-127.0.0.1:49254-2) (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

Whereas the consumer/producer terminal logs the following error:
WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-40647] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

My .conf files, .properties files and .bat files (as I'm using windows) are given below
kafka_server_jaas.conf file which is used for Kafka Server:
KafkaServer {org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required

username=kafkauser

password=Kafka123

user_kafkauser=Kafka123;

};

Client {org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required

username=kafkauser

password=Kafka123

servicename=zookeeper;

};

zookeeper_jaas.conf file which is used for Zookeeper:
Server {org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required

username=kafkauser

password=Kafka123

user_kafkauser=Kafka123;

};

kafka_client_jaas.conf which is used for Consumer and Producer:
KafkaClient {org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required

username=kafkauser

password=Kafka123;

};

server.properties:
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN

advertised.host.name=localhost

super.users=User:kafkauser

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

zookeeper.properties:
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper

clientPort=2181

maxClientCnxns=0

admin.enableServer=false

authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider

requireClientAuthScheme=sasl

jaasLoginRenewal=3600000

jaasEnabled=true

consumer.properties:
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

SASL.mechanism=PLAIN

group.id=test-consumer-group

producer.properties:
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

SASL.mechanism=PLAIN

compression.type=none

kafka-server-start.bat:
@echo off

IF [%1] EQU [] (

              echo USAGE: %0 server.properties

              EXIT /B 1

)

 

SetLocal

set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf

IF ["%KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (

    set KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:%~dp0../../config/log4j.properties

)

IF ["%KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (

   

    wmic os get osarchitecture | find /i "32-bit" >nul 2>&1

    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (

        set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Xms512M

    ) ELSE (

        set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx1G -Xms1G

    )

)

"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.Kafka %*

EndLocal

zookeeper-server-start.bat:
@echo off

IF [%1] EQU [] (

              echo USAGE: %0 zookeeper.properties

              EXIT /B 1

)

 

SetLocal

set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/kafka/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf

IF ["%KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (

    set KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:%~dp0../../config/log4j.properties

)

IF ["%KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (

    set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Xms512M

)

"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain %*

EndLocal

kafka-console-consumer.bat:
@echo off

SetLocal

set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/kafka/config/kafka_client_jaas.conf

set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M

"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer %*

EndLocal

kafka-console-producer.bat:
@echo off

SetLocal

set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/kafka/config/kafka_client_jaas.conf

set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M

"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer %*

EndLocal

